# How to filter extraneous Unicode values from a column?

Tags: postgresql, data-cleansing

I am cleaning up / priming our PostgreSQL 12 database for future data-related activities (e.g. data encryption). I have tried the following methods to delete non-basic Latin / basic accented Latin / punctuational values from one of our tables:

- `regexp_replace(field, '[^[:graph:]]', '', 'g')` and `SIMILAR TO '%[^[:graph:]]%'` (in our implementation, `[:print:]` is not working in `regexp_replace`)
- `btrim(field, '')` - not working for Unicode character-containing strings but only Latin strings.

However, the extraneous Unicode characters, even those embedded within acceptable (i.e., Latin and punctuational) values (e.g. `\ud83d`) do not get filtered / deleted from the values, hence, I couldn't prime the data.

What can I do to filter out only unacceptable Unicode values in `regexp_replace` and delete them, retaining only acceptable characters?

Comment: *"non-basic Latin / basic accented Latin / punctuational values"* is unclear to me. Does not seem to match either `[:graph:]` or `[:print:]` character classes. Please define acceptable characters exactly. The underlying OS and `LC_CTYPE` also influence character classes beyond the the 7-bit ASCII set.

Comment: Acceptable characters in our character set: alphanumeric, some accented characters (e.g., ñ and Ñ), apostrophe, dot and comma.

Comment: Still no clear definition.